# connection between azure functions time trigger and azure sql database with c# : error .how to fix it

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

i will trying to connect azure function with azure database sql using C# but i don't know how to fix this error. have you some ideas ??

**error :**
I did try and catch to see the exception

```
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exceptione)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

**and this is a code :**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions;


namespace azuretosharepoint
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the connection string from app settings and use it to create a connection.
                var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb-connection");
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var text = "SELECT * FROM PERSONNE ;";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                    {
                    // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
                    var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    log.LogInformation($"{rows} rows were updated");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPVa2.png)**

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The credentials are wrong. The full exception most likely contains more information. In any case, an account called `sqladmin` doesn't sound like something that should be used by any service

Comment: Please post the *full* exception text, not just the message. The full exception text contains any inner exceptions and a stack trace with the calls that resulted in this error. Posting the connection string (without sensitive information) would help too

Comment: non , credentials are right because I was able to connect with azure data studio but I’ll show you the exception :  Generated exception: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already modified the post and put the full eception

Comment: The post contains the Stacktrace, but not the exception details.

Comment: It looks like connection pooling is enabled (default) and you're hitting a pool-blocking situation where the system is forcing you to wait before trying again. See the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.poolblockingperiod?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511

The actual exception that's causing you to have to wait was thrown by a previous command you issued.

Comment: I put the image of debbugger, excuse me but I am a begginer

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) if you are very new to this service.

After checking your code, there is nothing wrong. The problem must be the connection. Please check if you modify the **password** in your **connection string**.
[image]

Another thing is to make sure you set the server firewall rules for your ip address.
[image]